# Deleting contacts from "All iPhone" also delets them from "All Exchange"?

Tags: iphone, contacts

On my iPhone SE, I found that my "Default Account" for Contacts was iPhone.  That was why newly created contacts would not sync with an Exchange Server.  So I changed it to Exchange.  I did not like the fact that migrating the iPhone contacts to the Exchange account needed either a 3rd party app or transferring through the cloud in some way.  So I handraulically re-typed the contacts as new contacts in the "All Exchange" group.  I made sure that the "All iPhone" group was unchecked.  This caused the new contacts to sync with Exchange Server.

To tie up lose ends, I made sure that only the "All iPhone" group was checked, then deleted the re-typed contacts from that group.  Then I made sure that only the "All Exchange" group was checked.  Lo and behold, the contacts were gone.

1) Is this a bug?

2) How do I avoid this?

3) And how do I prevent Contact settings from switching to iPhone?  I seem to be always switching it back over the years, after being burned repeatedly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All iPhone [or All iCloud if you have that set up] is the 'master list'.
All contacts are in that list.

All other lists are sub-sets of that.
Anything not in any sub-set will only appear in the master list.

If you delete something from the master list you are also deleting it from any & all sub-sets.

Comment: Thanks,Tetsujin.  I guess there is no account for Contacts that are only stored locally on the iPhone and nowhere else?  That's what I mistakenly thought "All iPhone" meant.